# Android id with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

As we can find android unique id usin native code like -

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

But please suggest me is their any way to do same thing using phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's the default behavior when you call `device.uuid` , at least on Phonegap 3.5.0. You can see that if you check the source code of `org.apache.cordova.device.Device`

```
public class Device extends CordovaPlugin {
...
    /**
     * Get the device's Universally Unique Identifier (UUID).
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getUuid() {
        String uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        return uuid;
    }
...
}
```